# UIScrollView with dynamic height and width depending of screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a UIScrollView and child view. Child view contains 14 dynamic height and width depending on screen size  button .
All top space constraint are connected with respective upper button , and top most button is connected with top of child view . Now i have taken a label at the end of the child view and I have connected it with bottom of child view, its working ok with iphone 7(i design on this), when I change simulator(5s, 6s ) it creates space between last button and bottom of child view of scroll view.

Comment: You need to take one mutable variable as CGFloat and add/manage height of each your subview and after set that var as height of contentSize of scrollView

Comment: You have more detail or some code like how's the child view added to the scroll view and the buttons' layouts?